# Noun meaning having made your mind up before having seen something

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> The movie *XYZ* is expected to be a flop. It was revealed that critic John Smith panned the movie without having  seen it. It is feared that other critics 
>   will hold the same [noun].

Possible answers that come to mind, but I don't like are:

A **bias**  may influence someone's views, but it doesn't necessitate having made their mind up.

**predjudice** doesn't necessitate ignorance. For example insurance companies may be *predjudiced* against young male drivers, but this doesn't come from ignorance. Also, in a modern context the term if inflammatory.

Comment: Maybe *bigotry*?

Comment: The verb _prejudge_ carries just the original sense {prejudge _verb_
[WITH OBJECT]
_Form a judgement on (an issue or person) prematurely and without having adequate information._
‘it is wrong to prejudge an issue on the basis of speculation’} {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudge)} so the use of the _ing_-form will work with a modification ('... will be equally guilty of prejudging').

Comment: 'Counting your chickens [before they've hatched]'?

Comment: Based on your title I'd say "gibberish".

Comment: @SteveLovell -- What is an "a thing"?

Comment: @HotLicks, good point, I didn't spot the second issue with the question title. I assume only one of "the" and "a" should be there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *preconception*. It necessitates ignorance because the speaker has his/her conceptions entrenched.